# Oracle table SAMPLE no longer updates

Tags: oracle, tablename

A few years ago, my Oracle table called SAMPLE stopped accepting update or insert commands.  I finally found that if I renamed the table all would work, so it appears SAMPLE may be a protected word, yet I don't see it on the Oracle reserved or protected word lists.  Any light on this would be appreciated.

Comment: `sample` is a keyword, but not reserved. You can create a table named SAMPLE. Instead of posting `stopped accepting update or insert commands.` post error message if there is any. What exactly `stop accepting..` means?

Comment: Yes, good point, thanks.    Error (from .Net) was ""Dynamic SQL generation failed. Either no base tables were found or more than one base table was found".   Actual call was:  adapter.Update(dataRows);  Odd thing is that this SAMPLE table worked fine for 12 years, and still works today, but stopped working for adapter.Update calls (but could be filled in direct SQL).  I probably should make a code snippet, but that might take a while before I can free up the table.

Comment: This sounds more like a problem with your process than the actual table. Why are you generating dynamic SQL? You need to explain *a lot more* about what you're doing (and why).

Answer (score 1):

We can see all the keywords for our version of Oracle by querying the `v$reserved_words` view:

```
SQL> select * from v$reserved_words rw
  2  where rw.keyword = 'SAMPLE'
  3  /

KEYWORD                            LENGTH R R R R D
------------------------------ ---------- - - - - -
SAMPLE                                  6 N N N N N

SQL>
```

This tells us that 'SAMPLE' is a keyword but not reserved in any context. So we are allowed to create objects called SAMPLE. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/dynviews_2134.htm#REFRN30204).